# CHM to EPUB Converter

Tags: conversion, ebook, chm, epub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to convert CHM files to EPUB/Kindle](https://superuser.com/questions/73638/software-to-convert-chm-files-to-epub-kindle)

I recently bought an iriver ebook reader but it doesn't support chm files.

I have bought a bunch of O'Reilly books and with them have the soft copy as well.

Some books convert quite well using calibre.

However, there is one book I have that just won't convert.

So I used HH to decompile it and now I have a bunch of html files.  These html files contain references to images in folders.

How can I now join them all into a single document which Calibre can read and properly convert into an epub or am I going about this the wrong way?

I've read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/73638/software-to-convert-chm-files-to-epub-kindle) but it removes the images and the images are quite important to the content.

Comment: Yes I know it's somewhat of a duplicate but if you read my question you'll see why I consider it to be different.